# What is the advantage of null assignment in Java?

Tags: java

I see a lot of code like this:

```
SomeObject someObject = null;

try{

   someObject = ObjectFactory.createSomeObject();
   ...
```

What is the advantage of doing this compared to this:

```
SomeObject someObject = ObjectFactory.createSomeObject();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an common used idiom, you have to initialize the connection with null, because Java only support initialization for class members, in this scope you have to initialize it with `null`, because `ConnectionFactory.create()` maybe also throws an exception.

You use this to widen the scope of your variable and use it later, for example to close your connection handle.

```
Connection connection = null;

try {
   connection = ConnectionFactory.create();

   [...]

   // More code which probably causes an exception

} catch(Exception e) {
   // Handle the exception
} finally {
    if(connection != null) {
      // Cleanup and close resources later
      connection.close()
    }
}
```

If you initialize the connection within the catch block it is not visible for the finally block or the following code.

Comment: The point being: if `connection` had been declared inside the `try` clause, its scope would be limited to that clause - so you couldn't close it outside, in the `finally` clause.

Comment: This is an example, not a answer to **What is the advantage of doing this**.

Answer (score 3):

It's a common pattern when creating objects that need to be destroyed or resources that need to be disposed of. For instance, with database connections:

```
Connection        connection = null;
PreparedStatement statement  = null;

try {
    connection = getConnection();
    statement  = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users");

    // ...
}
catch (SQLException exception) {
    // Handle error.
}
finally {
    if (statement  != null) statement .close();
    if (connection != null) connection.close();
}
```

If you declare the objects inside of the `try` block then they cannot be referenced inside the `finally` since it has a different scope. The declarations need to be outside the `try` but the assignments need to be inside so that exceptions during initialization can be caught.

The `close()` calls must be done inside of a `finally` block to ensure that the database resources are freed whether or not the database calls succeed.

Comment: It's a common "anti-idiom". Amongst other things it tends lead to buggy implementations. For instance, your code doesn't close the connection if the statement throws.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably related to the scope (visibility) of the someObject-variable, so the variable can be used later on outside the try-catch -block.

Answer (score 1):

It's an ill-advised little dance people play with `null`s in an attempt to merge a `try`-`finally` with a `try`-`catch`. It's frequently accompanied by bugs (NPE, not closing everything in the unhappy case, releasing resources not acquired, etc. - people are *so* inventive with bugs in sloppy code). Much better to split the two different forms of `try`, possibly into different methods. Unlike the `try`-`catch`-`finally` combo, the `finally` should be within the `catch`.

```
try {
    final SomeObject someObject = ObjectFactory.createSomeObject();
    try {
        ...
    } finally {
        someObject.dispose();
    }
} catch (SomeException exc) {
    throw AppropriateToTheCallerException(exc);
    // or printf
}
```

In JDK7, assuming `SomeObject` implements `AutoCloseable` you can write

```
try (final SomeObject someObject = ObjectFactory.createSomeObject()) {
    ...
} catch (SomeException exc) {
    throw AppropriateToTheCallerException(exc);
    // or printf
}
```

Note that the hidden "finally" goes before the `catch`. I would generally suggest separating resource and exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

If an exception might be thrown in the ObjectFactory.createSomeObject() method that you want to handle in your try/catch/finally block, this is the only way you can use someObject after exiting the try/catch/finally block.

Answer (score 0):

Using the try-catch-finally blocks, you can more easily handle any exceptions that occur.

You can't declare the variable inside the try block and access it outside of that block. So, you declare it outside any block. This is particularly helpful when you want to release resources in a finally block.