# What is the different between assigning a null to a valuable or not assign anything in java?

Tags: java

What is the different between:

```
Socket connection = null;
```

and

```
Socket connection;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083169/what-is-the-advantage-of-null-assignment-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a field (static or instance variable) then the two are broadly equivalent as `null` is the default value. (There's a subtle difference if a super-constructor calls an overridden method which sets the value, but that's a corner case.)

If it's a local variable, they're very different - in the first form, the local variable is *definitely assigned*, and the value can be read in the very next statement. In the second form, the variable *isn't* definitely assigned, and you won't be able to read it from code until such a point where the compiler can *prove* that a value will have been written:

```
void foo() {
  String x = null;
  String y;

  System.out.println(x)  // Fine, prints null
  System.out.println(y); // Compile-time error
}
```

Comment: So before local variable can be used, it must be declared and assigned.I am wondering why not give the local variable a default value?

Comment: @Ivan: Because it helps to prevent errors, where there's a code path you hadn't thought of - e.g. you've *assumed* that you'll always enter a loop, because you hadn't considered a particular scenario.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the context.

If `connection` is a field, then there is no difference.  Fields are default initialized, and a field with a reference type is default initialized to `null`.

If `connection` is a local variable, then the second form means that the `connection` variable is not initialized.  That's OK, but the compiler will insist that the variable is definitely initialized (later on) before you attempt to use its value.

Answer (score 1):

These answers are given in any book about basics of Java. When variable is used as a class field, then null will be assigned automatically. If variable was created in a method, it can't be used until null or some value is assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

The first declaration gives `connection` a **value of null**. This is totally valid code and will compile fine, though if you attempt to call a method on it you will get a NullPointerException.

The second declaration leaves `connection` **uninitialised**. You can initialise it later by assigning it a value, but if you try to access it before it is initialised your code won't even compile. Java (sensibly) has protections in the compiler/JIT to prevent you from ever accessing an uninitialised value.

The second version is useful in a couple of situations:

- When you want to declare a field in a class that will be initialised later in the constructor.
- When you want to declare a variable with a larger scope (e.g. in the top level scope within a method, so that several code blocks within the method can access the same value)

Answer (score -1):

Here we have 2 cases.

1. Primitives: 
   In this case, if we assign a value to a primitive that will be it's value. If we don't assign a value, the default value .. for a numeric type will be 0, for a boolean will be false...
2. Objects, non-primitives:
   In this case, if we assign a value .. let's say using *new*, we will have a new object with a new value.
   If we don't initialize it, the default value FOR ANY OBJECT (subclass of Object class), will be null

note. this is a very brief description of what happens ... this subject needs to be studied to have a clear and correct idea about it.

Comment: This is only true if the variable is a class or instance member.

Comment: right. if you don't assign a value (null) inside a method, the code won't compile

Comment: And *that* is only true if the variable is used before being set. Your answers are fundamentally flawed. There are more than two cases here.

Comment: Why would you declare a local variable if you don't use it ?

Comment: You could set it before you read it, but you're changing the subject. The statement made in your answer remains incorrect.